# How to do a MDX Except crossjoin dimension query

Tags: ssas, mdx

Consider the following data. I would like to get the NON{Country:USA & Gender:F} using MDX

```
- - - - - - - - - -  - - - - - - - - - - - 
| Country     |    Gender     |   Sales   |        
- - - - - - - - - -  - - - - - - - - - - - 
USA               M                1000
USA               F                500
Spain             M                200
Spain             F                600
```

What I want to extract would be:

```
- - - - - - - - - -  - - - - - - - - - - - 
| Country     |    Gender     |   Sales   |        
- - - - - - - - - -  - - - - - - - - - - - 
USA               M                1000
Spain             M                200
Spain             F                600
```

I tried to use crossjoin, union and except to do that, e.g.

```
    WITH SET [Test] AS
    [Country].[CountryCode].[USA] * Except ([Gender].members,{[Gender].[GenderCode].[F]}) +
    Except([Country].[CountryCode].members, {[Country].[CountryCode].[USA]}) * [Gender].members
    SELECT
       NON EMPTY [Test] ON ROWS,
       {[Measures].[Sales]} ON COLUMNS
        FROM [SalesCube]
```

It works, but may i know if there is any other simpler way to do it ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to exclude few combinations, you can use `Except` on the cross join with the excepted combinations as tuples like this:

```
WITH SET [Test] AS
Except(CrossJoin([Country].[CountryCode].members,
                 [Gender].members
                ),
       { ([Country].[CountryCode].[USA], [Gender].[GenderCode].[F]) }
      )
...
```

And syntactically, you an abbreviate `CrossJoin` as `*` and `Except` as `-`, as well as `Union` as `+`, which have the usual rules of precedence (`*` has higher precendece than `-` and `+`):

```
WITH SET [Test] AS
[Country].[CountryCode].members * [Gender].[GenderCode].members
-
{ ([Country].[CountryCode].[USA], [Gender].[GenderCode].[F]) }
...
```

Comment: Bearing in mind that using - instead of except isn't doing the actual set element removal but just subtracting the measure values. * is a short hand notation for Crossjoin, but - is not exactly equivalente to Except.

Comment: @nsousa No! Like `*` can be used as a cross join operator on sets and as a multiplication operator on values, `-` is an alias for `Except` if used on sets (see the documentation for minus used as set operator at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms145497.aspx) as well as a multiplication operator on values.

Comment: You're right, I was under the wrong impression. Thanks for that.